# useEffect with empty array doesn't behave as componentDidMount()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, react-hooks

I have the following problem. I need to set the state of the app component after  the onSnapshot event. That's why I have put that in the componentDidMount() and it works fine it logs the set user, however when I put the same code in a useEffect with an empty dependency array it logs null. Any ideas?

Here are the two components:

Class

```
class App extends Component<{}, AppState> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            currentUser: undefined,
        };
    }

    unsubscribeFromAuth = () => {};

    componentDidMount() {
        this.unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (userAuth) => {
            if (userAuth) {
                const userRef = await createUserProfileDoc(userAuth);

                userRef?.onSnapshot((snapShot) => {
                    this.setState({
                        currentUser: {
                            id: snapShot.id,
                            ...snapShot.data(),
                        },
                    });

                    console.log(this.state);
                });
            }
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.unsubscribeFromAuth();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header currentUser={this.state.currentUser} />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
                    <Route path="/shop" component={ShopPage} />
                    <Route path="/signin" component={SignInUpPage} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Functional

```
function App() {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        let unsubscribeFromAuth = () => {};
        const afterMount = () => {
            unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (userAuth) => {
                if (userAuth) {
                    const userRef = await createUserProfileDoc(userAuth);

                    userRef?.onSnapshot((snapShot) => {
                        setCurrentUser({
                            id: snapShot.id,
                            ...snapShot.data(),
                        });

                        console.log(currentUser);
                    });
                }
            });
        };
        afterMount();
        return () => {
            unsubscribeFromAuth();
        };
    }, []);
    return (
        <div>
            <Header currentUser={currentUser} />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
                <Route path="/shop" component={ShopPage} />
                <Route path="/signin" component={SignInUpPage} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting state and console logging the current value of that state in the same function will always return the old value.

Try this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
//...
const newCurrentUser = { id: snapShot.id,
 ...snapShot.data(),
}
setCurrentUser(newCurrentUser);
console.log(newCurrentUser);
```

```
//outside the useEffect()

console.log(currentUser) //<<---You will first see null then the actual current user after useEffect is done doing its work
```

Answer (score 1):

They act the same indeed, it's the difference between what you are logging and `setState` caveat that cause the issue.

The `setState` mechanism in both cases does not update the state immediately; an update happens after `componentDidMount`/effect were executed. At the time `console.log` is called, both states have `null`/`undefined` instead of user object. However, when you log `this.state`, due to asynchronous nature of `console.log`, you see in the console the updated state object. If you do `console.log(this.state.currentUser)` instead, you will see `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

The state setter is asynchronous, so you cannot get the updated value immediately after calling it. You should use another useEffect for this:

```
function App() {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(currentUser);
    }, [currentUser])


    useEffect(() => {
        let unsubscribeFromAuth = () => {};
        const afterMount = () => {
            unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (userAuth) => {
                if (userAuth) {
                    const userRef = await createUserProfileDoc(userAuth);

                    userRef?.onSnapshot((snapShot) => {
                        setCurrentUser({
                            id: snapShot.id,
                            ...snapShot.data(),
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        };
        afterMount();
        return () => {
            unsubscribeFromAuth();
        };
    }, []);
    return (...)
}
```

Bad example for your case, as you can keep using the local variable there, so just for reference - you can use a custom hook from my library if you really need to get the state value inside an async function ([Some demo to play](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-async-watcher-njuoc?file=/src/TestComponent.js)):

```
import { useAsyncWatcher } from "use-async-effect2";

function App() {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);  
    const currentUserWatcher = useAsyncWatcher(currentUser);

    useEffect(() => {
        let unsubscribeFromAuth = () => {};
        const afterMount = () => {
            unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (userAuth) => {
                if (userAuth) {
                    const userRef = await createUserProfileDoc(userAuth);

                    userRef?.onSnapshot((snapShot) => {
                        setCurrentUser({
                            id: snapShot.id,
                            ...snapShot.data(),
                        });
                        console.log(await currentUserWatcher()); // wait for updated state value
                    });
                }
            });
        };
        afterMount();
        return () => {
            unsubscribeFromAuth();
        };
    }, []);
    return (...)
}
```

Another approach with deep state ([Generic Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-async-deep-state-5c9d0?file=/src/TestComponent.js)):

```
import { useAsyncDeepState } from "use-async-effect2";

function App() {
    const [state, setState] = useAsyncDeepState({currentUser: null});  

    useEffect(() => {
        let unsubscribeFromAuth = () => {};
        const afterMount = () => {
            unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (userAuth) => {
                if (userAuth) {
                    const userRef = await createUserProfileDoc(userAuth);

                    userRef?.onSnapshot((snapShot) => {
                        await setState({
                          currentUser:{
                            id: snapShot.id,
                            ...snapShot.data(),
                          }
                        });
                        console.log(state.currentUser); 
                    });
                }
            });
        };
        afterMount();
        return () => {
            unsubscribeFromAuth();
        };
    }, []);
    return (...)
}
```